# Defining an object without calling its constructor in C++

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor

In C++, I want to define an object as a member of a class like this:

```
Object myObject;
```

However doing this will try to call it's parameterless constructor, which doesn't exist. However I need the constructor to be called after the containing class has done some initialising. Something like this.

```
class Program
{
public:
   Object myObject; //Should not try to call the constructor or do any initializing
   Program()
   {
      ...

      //Now call the constructor
      myObject = Object(...);
   }

}
```

Comment: Why not using dynamic initialization? auto_ptr/shared_ptr?

Comment: Global scope or member of a class? Your code doesn't match your question.

Comment: What is wrong with it calling the default constructor then after your initialization you set it to your object you care about, exactly like your code does? Or just make it a pointer: `Object* myObj;`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Store a pointer to an `Object` rather than an actual `Object`

thus:

```
class Program
{
public:
   Object* myObject; // Will not try to call the constructor or do any initializing
   Program()
   {
      //Do initialization
      myObject = new Object(...);  // Initialised now
   }

}
```

Don't forget to `delete` it in the destructor. Modern C++ helps you there, in that you could use an <s>auto_ptr</s> shared_ptr rather than a raw memory pointer.

Comment: If you do create a destructor, you should obey the rule of three.

Comment: @RomanKruglov • a `std::unique_ptr` is fine, as long as you also `= delete` the copy constructor and the assignment operator, or implement them to do the right thing.

Comment: You mean to `delete` `myObject` in the destructor of `Object` or `Program`?

Comment: @Eljay: Why would you need to `= delete` the copy constructor/assignment operator to use `std::unique_ptr`? My understanding is that, if any member of the class has a deleted copy constructor, [the class's copy constructor/assignment operators are implicitly deleted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Deleted_implicitly-declared_copy_constructor) (you'd have to write them explicitly if even a single `unique_ptr` is part of the instance state).

Comment: @ShadowRanger • if ones does `program2 = program;`, then program2 will have "stolen" the `myObject` unique_ptr from program.  If the copy constructor and assignment operator is deleted or implemented to do the right thing, `program` won't have its `myObject` member variable stolen out from under it.  (Well, since `myObject` is public, anyone could steal it.  That ought to be fixed too.)

Comment: @Eljay: That's the point of what I was linking earlier `program2 = program;` will fail because simply by having a `std::unique_ptr` member (which deletes its own copy constructor/copy assignment), its own copy constructor/assignment is also deleted. Using `= delete;` explicitly is redundant; the compiler already deletes them (precisely to prevent the problem you're describing). The problem you're describing sounds like [an issue with the old `std::auto_ptr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto_ptr#Semantics), which transferred ownership on copy; `std::unique_ptr` prevents that behavior.

Comment: @ShadowRanger • You're right, I stand corrected.  Thanks!  (I won't delete my mistaken comment, to preserve the thread for posterity.)

Comment: But using the `new` keyword still requires you pass in the parameters for the constructor of the object, right?

Answer (score 24):

Others have posted solutions using raw pointers, but a smart pointer would be a better idea:

```
class MyClass {
  std::unique_ptr<Object> pObj;
  // use boost::scoped_ptr for older compilers; std::unique_ptr is a C++0x feature
public:
  MyClass() {
    // ...
    pObj.reset(new Object(...));
    pObj->foo();
  }
  // Don't need a destructor
};
```

This avoids the need to add a destructor, and implicitly forbids copying (unless you write your own `operator=` and `MyClass(const MyClass &)`.

If you want to avoid a separate heap allocation, this can be done with boost's `aligned_storage` and placement new. Untested:

```
template<typename T>
class DelayedAlloc : boost::noncopyable {
  boost::aligned_storage<sizeof(T)> storage;
  bool valid;
public:
  T &get() { assert(valid); return *(T *)storage.address(); }
  const T &get() const { assert(valid); return *(const T *)storage.address(); }

  DelayedAlloc() { valid = false; }

  // Note: Variadic templates require C++0x support
  template<typename Args...>
  void construct(Args&&... args)
  {
    assert(!valid);
    new(storage.address()) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    valid = true;
  }

  void destruct() {
    assert(valid);
    valid = false;
    get().~T();
  }

  ~DelayedAlloc() { if (valid) destruct(); }
};

class MyClass {
  DelayedAlloc<Object> obj;
public:
  MyClass() {
    // ...
    obj.construct(...);
    obj.get().foo();
  }
}
```

Or, if `Object` is copyable (or movable), you can use `boost::optional`:

```
class MyClass {
  boost::optional<Object> obj;
public:
  MyClass() {
    // ...
    obj = Object(...);
    obj->foo();
  }
};
```

Comment: Using your first suggestion, I get

`The text ">" is unexpected.  It may be that this token was intended as a template argument list terminator but the name is not known to be a template.`

Answer (score 8):

You can fully control the object construction and destruction by this trick:

```
template<typename T>
struct DefferedObject
{
    DefferedObject(){}
    ~DefferedObject(){ value.~T(); }
    template<typename...TArgs>
    void Construct(TArgs&&...args)
    {
        new (&value) T(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
    }
public:
    union
    {
        T value;
    };
};
```

Apply on your sample:

```
class Program
{
public:
   DefferedObject<Object> myObject; //Should not try to call the constructor or do any initializing
   Program()
   {
      ...

      //Now call the constructor
      myObject.Construct(....);
   }

}
```

Big advantage of this solution, is that it does not require any additional allocations, and object memory allocated as normal, but you have control when call to constructor.

[Another sample link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b014f1f30dadf9a)

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to boost, there is a handy object that is provided called `boost::optional<>` - this avoids the need for dynamic allocation, e.g.

```
class foo
{
  foo()  // default std::string ctor is not called..
  {
    bar = boost::in_place<std::string>("foo"); // using in place construction (avoid temporary)
  }
private:
  boost::optional<std::string> bar;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

You may also be able to rewrite your code to use the constructor initializer list, if you can move off the other initialization into constructors:

```
class MyClass
  {
    MyObject myObject; // MyObject doesn't have a default constructor
  public:
    MyClass()
      : /* Make sure that any other initialization needed goes before myObject in other initializers*/
      , myObject(/*non-default parameters go here*/)
      {
      ...
      }
  };
```

You need to be aware that following such a pattern will lead you to a path where you do a lot of work in constructors, which in turn leads to needing to grasp exception handling and safety (as the canonical way to return an error from a constructor is to throw an exception).

Comment: I just came across with this problem. If i call the specified constructor in intialising list it works as a charm. If i don't, the default constructor will be called. I don't understand how the compiler knows that later on I initialize the object, because at the moment the program encounters the declarations of my object `MyClass obj;` there is no sign for the compiler to know "i wont call here the default constructor, i Shall wait until the initializing list"

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu - I'm not entirely certain, but I'm guessing that maybe the order of the class declaration is making you think that's the order of initialization.  The initializer list is actually done before anything else in the construction of the class, so it's useful to set things up that you will need later on in the constructor as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pointer (or a smart pointer) to do that.  If you do not use a smart pointer, do make sure that your code free memory when the object is deleted.  If you use a smart pointer, do not worry about it.

```
class Program
{
public:
   Object * myObject;
   Program():
      myObject(new Object())
   {
   }
   ~Program()
   {
       delete myObject;
   }
   // WARNING: Create copy constructor and = operator to obey rule of three.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## A trick that involves anonymous union and placement new

this is similar to jenkas' answer but more direct

```
class Program
{
public:
   union{
   Object myObject;
   }; //being a union member in this case prevents the compiler from attempting to call the (undefined) default constructor
   
   Program()
   {
      ...

      //Now call the constructor
      new (&myObject) Object(...);
   }
   ~Program()
   {
      myobject.~Object(); //also make sure you explicitly call the object's destructor
   }

}
```

however the catch is that now you must explicitly define all the special member functions as the compiler will delete them by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using an `union`

Members of an union are uninitialized

Try creating an union

```cpp
template <typename T>
union uninitialized_value_of
{ T value; };
```

Then whenever you want to get an uninitialized value. Create an object of `uninitialized_value_of` with the type you want and take the reference to its member `value`

### Example

```cpp
class Program
{
    uninitialized_value_of<Object> MyObject;
    //Rest of your class
    //...
}
```